# Rails 5: Join 2 large text files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

In my Rails app, client uploads files in chunks (100 kB - 5 MB) via API.
(It upload each chunks using repeatedly the same HTTP POST request on API).

On the server-side, I store the first uploaded file in specific directory, by moving tempfile from upload:

```
 tmp = params[:file_pack].tempfile
 path = '/xxx/xxx.txt'

 FileUtils.move tmp.path, path
```

Next, I want to append the other chunks (second, third, etc.) - whioch come in next request over HTTP - to the end of this first chunk. So I want to collect all chunks in one file.

What is the most efficient way to append one file to the end of another large file?

It seems that the most popular way is a using `File.open(path, "a")`, but is it the most efficient way? Is this `File.open` load whole file into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append some file to the end of another, I've used:

```
File.open(path, 'a') { |f| f << params[:file_pack].tempfile.read }
```

where

- `path` is a path to destination file
- `a` means that the pointer is at the end of file (if file doesn't exist, it should create it)
- `params[:file_pack]` is a uploaded file over HTTP to API
- `.tempfile` gives access to temporary uploaded file

  I've tested it by adding a file with size of 29B to the file with size of 279MB and it works very fast. I haven't make a more detailed tested, but I hope this summary will be useful for someone.

Comment: I wonder what is more efficient/suitable on linux - your method or this shell command (executed from ruby) `%x( cat chunk.txt >> file.txt )`

Comment: I've tested it manually and I think that `cat` operation takes longer, but I didn't make a well-detailed benchmark tests for that, so correct me if I'm wrong.